# After doesn't work on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

I'd like to user `:after` with SASS but it seems not working on IE11...

My code :

```
.radio {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
  line-height: $radio-height;
  margin: 5px 0;

  > label {
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:after {
      // not working
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 12px;
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 12px;
      z-index: 1;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Main issue : `:after` is not visible in the document...

**Edit #1**

Doctype : `<!DOCTYPE html>`

IE Screen :

[image]

**Edit #2**

CodePen : http://codepen.io/tonymx227/pen/kXwLBL

Comment: Have you checked that your IE doesn't run in compatibility mode and your page has the correct doctype?

Comment: See edit #1 with `doctype` and dev tools...

Comment: Give `display: block;` to `&:after` block.

Comment: See edit with the entire code of `&:after` block and it doesn't work too...

Comment: `:after` pseudoelement is old, it's better to use `::after`. However, in the screenshot we can see the `::after` in the right panel, but is strikethroughed.

Comment: `:after` or `::after` doesn't work on IE11... My code works on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Add a working example. The post as this is not useful to help you. If you share a working example (stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net) we can see better the problem. See how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See edit #2 with CodePen...

Comment: @tonymx227 I've checked your codepen example in my IE11, its working fine...

Comment: Can I get a screen of your IE version and the radio render?

Comment: I found the issue, it was an issue using `calc()` it doesn't work on IE11 if you're trying to use something like `calc(#{$height} / 2)`...